# Push Notifications are "Sometimes" not delivered

Tags: php, android, ios, push-notification

I am facing a strange problem in our system where the push notifications (to iOS and to Android) are not being **always** delivered to the mobile devices despite the fact that am getting Success response on the delivery of those messages (from Apple and from Google).

The backend is in PHP. Here is the code I use to send the push notifications in iOS. It returns **Success: 156** for example yet the push is not **always** delivered.

Also for iOS, is there a way for me to know the reason why the response is coming back as 0 (failure)?

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pushcert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '');
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if ($fp) {
    $body['aps'] = array(
                    'alert' => $message,
                    'badge' => 1,
                    'sound' => 'default'
    );

    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
    return "Success: $result";
}
else
{
    return "Failed: $err $errstr";
}
```

Here is a snippet of Android Code:

```
$apiKey = ANDROID_PUSH_API_KEY;

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';


$fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $registatoin_ids,
                'data' => $message
                );

$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

For Android, I do get success responses too yet the message is sometime delivered to the device and sometimes not:
**{"multicast_id":5182490226054200549,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1495238429549628%31ecb33bf9fd7ecd"}]}**

Comment: how much data contain in payload? can you check its size,  if it is beyond 4 kb so it will not be deliver , to your device

Comment: No, it is much less than 4KB. Also the same text (notification for new messages for example) can be delivered to the same device once and then the same message would not be delivered to the same device on a second or third time

Comment: so check device token